# Hosting an Angular application on two different hosts

Tags: node.js, angular

Is there any way to host the same Angular app on two different hosts (different IP or different port) using Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.angular-cli.json` file allows you to specify Angular-CLI configuration options; including the default hostname and port.

```
serve: Properties to be passed to the serve command
  • port (number): The port the application will be served on. Default is 4200.
  • host (string): The host the application will be served on. Default is localhost.
```

You can define the used port in the `.angular-cli.json` file by defining the property like this:

```
{
    "defaults": {
        "serve": {
            "port": 2500
        }
    }
}
```

---

See the Angular CLI documentation for more info and a complete listing of configuration options: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

---

**Command line solution**

If you're looking for a command line solution that does not require and configuration editing, simply run the `ng serve` or `ng serve --prod` commands with the optional `host` and `port` commands.

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201`

Using these optional command line parameters, you can simply run the command twice, each with different a host and port.

---

*Side note:*
That being said, unless you are going to be serving your Angular application using the Angular CLI, you'll likely need to configure these options using the methods associated with your hosting platform.

Comment: I was under impression OP is asking about hosting it on two different ports _at the same time_. Could be wrong though, let's wait for clarification.

Comment: I've added a command line variant to my answer which should fulfill this requirement.

Comment: @Trent, the command line solution works good. Just to add one more help for my project, is it possible to load different style.css file for different serves. say i have two style.css files and i want to load one for one serve (style.css -1 for serve-1)and the other (style.css -2 for serve-2).

Comment: Yes, simply use the —styles command line parameter and pass a string of the relative path to your global style sheet; you can also pass an array of strings if you’d like to include multiple.